# How to add Python script to registry using Ctypes and kernel32.dll

Tags: python, registry, ctypes, kernel32

I'm trying to add my program to registry and this is my code...

```
def regc():
reg = windll.kernel32
print(reg)
hkey = 'HKEY_CURRENT_USER'
lsubkey = 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
reserved = 0
flag = 'REG_OPTION_BACKUP_RESTORE'
samdesired = 'KEY_ALL_ACCESS'
ipsec = None
handle = reg.RegCreateKeyExA(hkey, lsubkey, reserved, flag, samdesired, ipsec, None)
```

Its not giving me any errors but it still isn't creating a new key in registry. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To use `ctypes` correctly, define `.argtypes` and `.restype` to do error checking of your parameters.  Many of the types used are wrong.  `hkey`, `flag`, and `samdesired` are not strings, for example.  The return value is not a handle, but a status.  The return value is an output parameter (`pkhResult` in the docs).  You **must** read the documentation and examine the header files of all the variable definitions carefully.

Also, in Python 3 strings are Unicode, so use the `W` form of Windows APIs to accept Unicode strings.  Use raw strings (`r'...'`) for the subkey since it contains backslashes that could be interpreted as escape codes.

Here's a working example:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes import wintypes as w

# Values found from reading RegCreateKeyExW documentation,
# using Go To Definition on the types in Visual Studio,
# and printing constants in a C program, e.g. printf("%lx\n",KEY_ALL_ACCESS);

HKEY = c_void_p
PHKEY = POINTER(HKEY)
REGSAM = w.DWORD
LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = c_void_p
LSTATUS = w.LONG

# Disposition values
REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY = 0x00000001
REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY = 0x00000002

ERROR_SUCCESS = 0

HKEY_CURRENT_USER = c_void_p(0x80000001)
REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE = 0
KEY_ALL_ACCESS = 0x000F003F

dll = WinDLL('kernel32')
dll.RegCreateKeyExW.argtypes = HKEY,w.LPCWSTR,w.DWORD,w.LPWSTR,w.DWORD,REGSAM,LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES,PHKEY,w.LPDWORD
dll.RegCreateKeyExW.restype = LSTATUS

hkey = HKEY_CURRENT_USER
lsubkey = r'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run'
options = REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE
samdesired = KEY_ALL_ACCESS

# Storage for output parameters...pass by reference.
handle = HKEY()
disp = w.DWORD()

status = dll.RegCreateKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, lsubkey, 0, None, options, samdesired, None, byref(handle), byref(disp))
if status == ERROR_SUCCESS:
    print(f'{disp=} {handle=}')
```

Output:

```
disp=c_ulong(2) handle=c_void_p(3460)
```

The disposition value of 2 indicates the key already exists (`REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY`).

You could also install [pywin32](https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/) and use `win32api.RegCreateKey` or `win32api.RegCreateKeyEx` where all the work is already done for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helped. Looking at this solution made me realize how wrong my approach was trying to use ctypes lol I need to read that documentation properly